# Shell menu item separator

Tags: c#, contextmenu, windows-shell, windows-shell-extension-menu

My question may be the repeated one here but even after googling i havn't got the solution yet.

I have added a shell context menu item for files i.e. when you right click on a file within explorer the menu shows my custom menu item.

I have used -

HKLM\Software\Classes*\shell\myappname 
HKLM\Software\Classes*\shell\myappname\command

But what i am not able to do is to add a separator within that context menu.

I am using C# 2005 for creating my windows application.

Could someone help solve my problem.

Thanks for sharing your valuable time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the following link: [Extending Shortcut Menus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776820(VS.85).aspx)
I think there is no keyword to add a separator but to create a new entry at the same level. The new set of entries will appear in a new group.

Comment: Thanks buddy! Not my answer but provided yet another helpful link.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create a shell context menu handler to take full control over the context menu content.  You should not write this in C# until .NET 4.0 becomes widely available.  For now you can use C++, [this web page](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/shellextguide1.aspx#modifyingmenu) has an example.  A wrapper is [described here](http://chestermr.blogspot.com/2007/03/shell-extension-context-menu.html), no idea if it is any good.

Comment: Thanks nobugz for providing another link.